# Autowired Spring Beans across Java packages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I’m attempting to break my project up into three modules: core, admin and user so that I can share common code via core. The problem is that I can’t get Spring to pickup the autowired beans across different main packages, when I have everything in the same package it works.

In the com.mickeycorp.core package I have the models, services, etc that I want the admin and user modules to use. In com.mickeycorp.admin is the my WebApplicationStarter (extends SpringBootServletInitializer) where I’ve got:

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(SpringConfiguration.class);
    return application.sources(WebApplicationStarter.class);
}
```

Which I believe should pickup my configuration class where I have the following:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mickeycorp")
public class SpringConfiguration {

}
```

Clearly I’ve misunderstood something.. I thought that setting ComponentScan would have Spring scan through packages under com.mickeycorp for component annotations?

Comment: WebApplicationStarter, is that class annotated? What annotations?

Comment: @StefaanNeyts Yep, it just has `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: Did you forget to put the core module in the classpath of admin and user module by any chance? By Maven dependency or in a lib folder in admin/user module.

Comment: @MystyxMac No, admin/user modules have the Maven dependency and compile correctly.

Comment: Why use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext? Can you try to use configure() { return application.sources( new Class[] { WebApplication.class, SpringConfiguration.class } ); }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was on the right track.. adding `@ComponentScan` was only a third of the way there and is correct but it doesn't configure Spring to scan for other types - it only covers `@Component` `@Repository`, `@Service`, or `@Controller` annotations. I had to add the following to pickup `@Entity` and `@Repository`:

```
@EntityScan("com.mickeycorp.core")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mickeycorp.core")
```

Overriding `SpringApplicationBuilder` is also unnecessary in this case as the `SpringConfiguration` class is automatically picked up.

References:

[Spring Docs: Entity Scan](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityScan.html)

[Spring Docs: EnableJpaRepositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html)

Answer (score 2):

`@ComponentScan` annotation has to be used.

Please refer the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) which says

> Either `basePackageClasses()` or `basePackages()` (or its alias `value()`) may be specified to define specific packages to scan.
>
> ```
> @ComponentScan(basePackages={"package1","package2"})
> ```

Comment: Yeah.. this is already stated in the accepted answer. Along with that `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` are also required.